# SharePoint 2013 Excel WebPart

Tags: web-part, excel, excel-services

I created new excel webpart. I got this error :

> The trial period for SharePoint Server has expired.
>   [image]

I researched on net and i found this solve :

> Run--> inetmgr-->Application Pools--> SharePoint Central Administrator--> Advanced Sttings--> Identity (change the account)
>
> Or add the current application pool identity account to local Administrator group.
>
> Run "iisreset"
>
> Still you have same issue, there might be some share point secure sources not configured correctly . You need to run "SharePoint Configuration wizard" or run 
>   "psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources" command(c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Bin\psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources)

I checked application pool identity and run iisreset. But the problem didn't solve. Then i tried the second advice. When I click the psconfig.exe, it's closing  instantly. So I'm not running  "cmd secureresources" .

How can I solve this problem with another way?

My Application Pool :
[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Trial Version?

Comment: No, I'm using licensed products @ArsalanAdamKhatri

Comment: Please check is your application pool for Office Web Apps or SharePoint web application where this web-part is used  is running under network credentials or local administrator ? it should run under local administrator. after changing please reset the application pool reset the iis.

Comment: @AkarshGupta I didn't find SharePoint web application where this web-part is used is running under network credentials or local administrator. I added my Application Pool under my questions. Please check it. Could you give me advice?

Comment: Check the application pool for your web application and check the credentials for that application pool. for eg. you have SharePoint-80 as an application pool is this the same application pool for which the associated web application give this error for excel webpart issue ?